# Java socket accept queue length

Tags: java, sockets, queue, serversocket

According to the Sun's documentation on ServerSocket:

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a request to connect) is set to 50. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full, the connection is refused.

How can I increase the the queue length? It's my server's bottle-neck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ServerSocket constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int%29) with the `backlog` parameter.

You may also want to consider using a Thread pool (or really an [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) to dispatch incoming requests.  Depending on how you architect it, this will generally lead to better throughput.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `backlog` parameter of the constructor ([Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int%29)).  Keep in mind that you won't be able to increase the queue past the operating system limits, though.  This is to prevent SYN attacks - see this [article](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1729) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is another constructor for ServerSocket.

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)
```

where backlog is the connection queue size you want. The max 50 only applied to the default constructor that takes `int port`

Answer (score 0):

To limit the connection refused be sure you process all of the connect requests for each select poll before doing any of the send/receive processing for that poll.